# quick way to use "changes" from job's description?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When a job builds, ususally jenkins prints out all the revisions that were built within the "Changes" section. Is there a quick and easy way to use that as an env variable perhaps? Or any other convenient way that is.

Comment: Are you doing concerned about the git or source repository changes? Do you want those changelogs in environment variable? Why?

Comment: I want the change list from the build into an env variable or object, because I want to use them later in some descriptions

Answer (score 0):

You can access it from your `pipeline script` or from your `jenkinsfile`
like that `${env.BUILD_NUMBER}`

If you want to view all your `env` variables you can print them in this way :

```
sh 'env | sort'
```

Comment: The only thing thats close there to the changes list is RUN_CHANGES but this is only url link rather than changes list. Or I am missing something there?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I understand that you would like to read the changes in source repo in the current build at some stage.

You don't have to save it to environment variable. In any stage, use `currentBuild.changeSets` to access the change logs related to that build.

Let's say you want to add the commit messages as job description. You can parse `currentBuild.changeSets` like below.

```
def formatGitChangeLog(changeSetList) {
    def commit_msg_log = ""
        for (setItem in changeSetList) {
            for (change in setItem.getLogs()) {
                //The following line concatenates all git author and commit message with a hyphen -.
                commit_msg_log += "${change.getAuthor().getDisplayName()} - ${change.getMsg()}"
            }
        }
    return commit_msg_log
}
```

The pipeline could be something like below:

```
pipeline{
    stage('some name') {
        steps {
            currentBuild.description = formatGitChangeLog(currentBuild.changeSets)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok I see what you meant, no actually I want to pass the "changes" outside of the pipeline, you know as a documentation, but I suppose that this should suffice

Comment: I would recommend you to avoid adding unnecessary values to environment. Instead pass it as parameter to another pipeline while calling the second one.

Comment: I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'formatGitChangeLog' `

Comment: You should declare the method. It's a custom method anyone could write. Write it in pipeline after the pipeline {} is closed. 
Or add the formatGitChangeLog method to shared libraries so it can be used across projects.

Comment: ah sorry, ok I'll try that